# How to use wolfram engine with mBlock

Tags: education, free-wolfram-engine

Has anyone tried to make wolfram engine work with mBlock user interface? I thought I saw a webpage once but can’t find it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a Wolfram Summer School project last year, maybe you will find this helpful: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1729082